# How to turn 3 column design into a table with last column having a background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've come to you for help, I developing a website with bootstrap 3 and looking to implement a table for one of the columns.

The table has 3 columns with the last one having a vertical background of blue with rounded corners. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I have made a table but not sure where to go from here. Any help would be awesome.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>price /month</th>
            <th># loads /month</th>
            <th>you save</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$90</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$120</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>$12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$160</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>$12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$190</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>$22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bootstrap you may want to get rid of the table striping but here's pretty close what you're looking for:

JS fiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/gf44a/)

CSS

```
.topbg {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #6699FF;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}

.cbg {
padding: 5px;
    background-color: #6699FF;
}

.bottombg {
padding: 5px;
background-color: #6699FF;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>price /month</th>
            <th># loads /month</th>
            <th class="topbg">you save</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>$50</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td class="cbg">$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$90</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td class="cbg">$2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$120</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td class="cbg">$12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$160</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td class="cbg">$12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>$190</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td class="bottombg">$22</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write out the code exactly, but the general idea is you want to use the [:last-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) to select the last cell in each row and apply a background color to that. You can set the border radius of the top and bottom cells in the last column to get the rounded edges.